# I am getting an error with Initializing my firebase application

Tags: javascript, firebase, expo, instagram

I am going through https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b2L_10gHVnM SimCoder Instagram clone turorial. At 27:05 He types :

```
if(firebase.apps.length === 0){
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
}
```

I have gone through this video turorial and I am getting an error with this specific code. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZmEM.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOGIh.png)

I have tried if `(!firebase.apps || !firebase.apps.length) { ... }`

I am still very fresh to javascript, so i am not understanding properly at the moment. Any help would be appreciated.

also when I start my expo project on command prompt I get this error after it loads [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6miPA.jpg)

Comment: try `firebase.apps` instead of `!firebase.apps` and change `||` to `&&`, i'm thinking like `if firebase.apps is defined and its length is not 0`

Comment: I am still not understanding, I have tried that too. How should I write it exactly?

Comment: Which Firebase SDK version are you using?

Comment: How can I find my SDK version? @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: I am using the latest one